# Encoding of bash terminal (representation of Cyrillic letters)

Tags: bash, character-encoding, git-bash

I have been using [git-bash terminal](https://git-scm.com/downloads), but, as I suppose, after editing font I have got a trouble - Cyrillic characters are not represented in the terminal. Instead of them it shows this: `\xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8f\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe!`.

I got this string using API:

```
import requests
import os


api_key = os.getenv('yandex_praktikum_api_key')


HEADERS = {
    'Authorization': f'OAuth {api_key}'
}


response = requests.get(
    'https://praktikum.yandex.ru/api/user_api/homework_statuses/',
    params={'from_date': 0},
    headers=HEADERS
)


print(response.text)
```

I tried to fix this by changing font back to Lucida Console (14px), but it didn't work. I checked my terminal encoding typing `echo $LC_CTYPE` and got `ru_RU.UTF-8`. Then after typing `$LANG` I got empty string. So, how can I fix it?

OS: Windows 10. File encoding is UTF-8. Terminal type is x-term.

Locale shows this:

```
User@DESKTOP-CVQ282P MINGW64 ~/Desktop
$ locale
LANG=C.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and share a [mcve] - how did you get described string from `Принято!`?

Comment: @VladMikheenko Can you try setting `LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"`?